# Cefsharp blank pdf window

Tags: pdf, cefsharp

I'm currently using Cefsharp to frame in a web application but I'm having trouble getting the dynamically generated pdfs to open or download. Currently when I run one of them I get a new window that pops up but it's blank.   When I click the reports from Google Chrome directly it is opening a new tab but then ultimately downloading the pdf - I'd be OK with either handling with local pdf viewer or a download.  After some fairly extensive googling I'm finding myself confused seeing issues with the PDF viewer not being supported in earlier versions (I'm using Cefsharp version 63.0.3.0) to having to handle the stream with some additional methods like IRequesetHandler but I'm not having any luck

Comment: How are you opening the `PDF` exactly? Please provide some code

Comment: Ah - therein lies at least one of my problems.  I don't have access to the source.  Any other suggestions or possible ways around that?

Comment: What code did you write?

Comment: I don't have access to the source of the web based application that I've framed into this Winform app via Cefsharp is what I mean - is that what you're asking?

Comment: It's just not enough information for me to even guess what's going on.